# Django/PostgreSQL Full Text Search - Different search results when using SearchVector versus SearchVectorField on AWS RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to use the Django `SearchVectorField` to support full text search. However, I'm getting different search results when I use the `SearchVectorField` on my model vs. instantiating a `SearchVector` class in my view. The problem is isolated to an AWS RDS PostgreSQL instance. Both perform the same on my laptop.

Let me try to explain it with some code:

```
# models.py

class Tweet(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tweet_id

    tweet_id = models.CharField(max_length=25, unique=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    text_search_vector = SearchVectorField(null=True, editable=False)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [GinIndex(fields=['text_search_vector'])]
```

I've populated all rows with a search vector and have established a trigger on the database to keep the field up to date.

```
# views.py

query = SearchQuery('chance')
vector = SearchVector('text')

on_the_fly = Tweet.objects.annotate(
    rank=SearchRank(vector, query)
).filter(
    rank__gte=0.001
)

from_field = Tweet.objects.annotate(
    rank=SearchRank(F('text_search_vector'), query)
).filter(
    rank__gte=0.001
)

# len(on_the_fly) == 32
# len(from_field) == 0
```

The `on_the_fly` queryset, which uses a `SearchVector` instance, returns 32 results. The `from_field` queryset, which uses the `SearchVectorField`, returns 0 results.

The empty result prompted me to drop into the shell to debug. Here's some output from the command line in my `python manage.py shell` environment:

```
>>> qs = Tweet.objects.filter(
...     tweet_id__in=[949763170863865857, 961432484620787712]
... ).annotate(
...     vector=SearchVector('text')
... )
>>> 
>>> for tweet in qs:
...     print(f'Doc text: {tweet.text}')
...     print(f'From db:  {tweet.text_search_vector}')
...     print(f'From qs:  {tweet.vector}\n')
... 
Doc text: @Espngreeny Run your 3rd and long play and  compete for a chance on third down.
From db:  '3rd':4 'chanc':12 'compet':9 'espngreeni':1 'long':6 'play':7 'run':2 'third':14
From qs:  '3rd':4 'a':11 'and':5,8 'chance':12 'compete':9 'down':15 'espngreeny':1 'for':10 'long':6 'on':13 'play':7 'run':2 'third':14 'your':3

Doc text: No chance. It was me complaining about Girl Scout cookies. <url-removed-for-stack-overflow>
From db:  '/aggcqwddbh':13 'chanc':2 'complain':6 'cooki':10 'girl':8 'scout':9 't.co':12 't.co/aggcqwddbh':11
From qs:  '/aggcqwddbh':13 'about':7 'chance':2 'complaining':6 'cookies':10 'girl':8 'it':3 'me':5 'no':1 'scout':9 't.co':12 't.co/aggcqwddbh':11 'was':4
```

You can see that the search vector looks very different when comparing the value from the database to the value that's generated via Django.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would happen? Thanks!

Comment: replace `F('text_search_vector')` with `'text_search_vector'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SearchQuery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/search/#SearchQuery) translates the terms the user provides into a search query object that the database compares to a search vector. By default, all the words the user provides are passed through the [Stemming algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) , and then it looks for matches for all of the resulting terms.
there two issue need to be solved first gave stemming algorithm information about language.

```
query = SearchQuery('chance' , config="english")
```

and second is replace this line

```
rank=SearchRank(F('text_search_vector'), query)
```

with

```
rank=SearchRank('text_search_vector', query)
```

about the missing word in `text_search_vector` this is standard procedure of [Stemming algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming) to remove common word known as [stop word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop-words)

Comment: Thanks, your advice seems to help. There's one issue I still can't figure out. When running the search on-the-fly using `SearchQuery('chance', config='english')` I get 0 results. If I drop the `config` argument, I get a result more similar to the database. On the other hand. querying the database without `config` results in an empty queryset, while including it returns logical results. Can you explain this difference? I remember setting the `config='english'` while setting up the db trigger - could that be related?

Comment: @Naqib If you replace the F objects with string column name how would you combine two SearchVectorFields in one SearchQuery if you want to full text search in both with weight, for example?

Comment: Looking at the output of `.explain(analyze=True)` it seems the only difference between using an F Expression and the field name in quotes is: `Sort Key: (ts_rank(to_tsvector(COALESCE((text_search_vector)::text, ''::text))` without the F Expression and `Sort Key: (ts_rank(text_search_vector, ...)` when the F Expression is used. using the F Expression returns much faster, but is less accurate.